# Credits in spotlight.app

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight

At */System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj* There is a fake called "Credits.rtf" only containing some random text.

Is it an easter egg or something malicious?

p.s it's also in the other xx.iproj folders.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Let's just assume it's a placeholder & if no credits need giving, then Mom gets it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default text inside the same Credits.rtf file when creating a new OS X Application in Xcode.

I assume Apple didn't bother changing it since they figured no one would bother looking.